# How to configure OTEL collector with Spring app using micrometer library and java instrumentation agent to get metrics

Tags: spring, prometheus, javaagents, micrometer, open-telemetry

**Issue**

Otel collector instrumentation agent does not forward prometheus metrics from Spring app correctly

**Local reproduction steps**

1. Simple java springboot app with gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
}
```

2. OTEL Collector running as a docker container with the following files

`docker-compose.yml`

```
  otel-collector:
      image: otel/opentelemetry-collector
      command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
      volumes:
        - ./config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
      ports:
        - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
        - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
        - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
        - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
        - "4317:4317"   # OTLP gRPC receiver
        - "4318:4318"   # OTLP http receiver
        - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
```

`config.yml`

```
receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: "Book"
          scrape_interval: 5s
          static_configs:
            - targets: ["localhost:9080"]
processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "localhost:9090"

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus]
```

3. Prometheus running as docker container

`docker-compose.yml`

```
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.17.1
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=200h'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9090
```

`prometheus.yaml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
```

**Scenario**

1. I start the OTEL Collector and Prometheus using docker
2. I run the following command below to auto instrument my spring java app

```
java -javaagent:./opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
-Dotel.javaagent.extensions=./opentelemetry-micrometer-1.5-1.13.0-alpha.jar \
-Dotel.instrumentation.spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure.enabled=false \
-Dotel.javaagent.debug=true \
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=prometheus \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=none \
-Dotel.exporter.prometheus.metrics.endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:4317 \
-Dotel.exporter.prometheus.port=9080 \
-Dotel.resource.attributes="service.name=helloapp" \
-Dotel.instrumentation.micrometer.base-time-unit=s \
-Dotel.instrumentation.micrometer.prometheus-mode.enabled=true \
-jar build/libs/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Issue:**

- Prometheus metrics exported by Instrumentation agent are different compared to Metrics received by collector and subsequently forwarded to Prometheus docker app
- Expected prometheus metrics

> ````
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_utilization gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_utilization Recent cpu utilization for the whole system
> process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_utilization 0.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage Measure of memory used process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="Metaspace",type="non_heap"}
> 4.289408E7 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="G1 Eden Space",type="heap"} 6291456.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="G1 Old Gen",type="heap"}
> 2.0279808E7 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="Compressed Class
> Space",type="non_heap"} 5806728.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="CodeHeap 'profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 1.2102912E7 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="CodeHeap
> 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 1271552.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="G1 Survivor Space",type="heap"}
> 5671744.0 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{pool="CodeHeap 'non-profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 3989888.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_threads_count gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_threads_count Number of executing threads process_runtime_jvm_threads_count 12.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit Measure of max obtainable memory process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit{pool="G1 Old Gen",type="heap"}
> 4.294967296E9 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit{pool="Compressed Class
> Space",type="non_heap"} 1.073741824E9 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit{pool="CodeHeap 'profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 1.22908672E8 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit{pool="CodeHeap
> 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 5840896.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit{pool="CodeHeap 'non-profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 1.22908672E8 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_memory_init gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_memory_init Measure of initial memory requested
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="Metaspace",type="non_heap"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="G1 Eden
> Space",type="heap"} 2.5165824E7 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="G1 Old Gen",type="heap"}
> 2.43269632E8 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="Compressed Class
> Space",type="non_heap"} 0.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="CodeHeap 'profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 2555904.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="CodeHeap
> 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 2555904.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="G1 Survivor Space",type="heap"}
> 0.0 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{pool="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 2555904.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_classes_loaded_total counter
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_classes_loaded_total Number of classes loaded since JVM start process_runtime_jvm_classes_loaded_total 9284.0
> 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed Measure of memory committed
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="Metaspace",type="non_heap"}
> 4.3384832E7 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="G1 Eden Space",type="heap"}
> 5.24288E7 1660037708660 process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="G1 Old Gen",type="heap"} 3.7748736E7 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="Compressed Class
> Space",type="non_heap"} 6029312.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="CodeHeap 'profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 1.212416E7 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="CodeHeap
> 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 2555904.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="G1 Survivor
> Space",type="heap"} 6291456.0 1660037708660
> process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{pool="CodeHeap 'non-profiled
> nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 3997696.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_classes_current_loaded gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_classes_current_loaded Number of classes currently loaded process_runtime_jvm_classes_current_loaded 9310.0
> 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_cpu_utilization gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_cpu_utilization Recent cpu utilization for the process process_runtime_jvm_cpu_utilization 0.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_classes_unloaded_total counter
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_classes_unloaded_total Number of classes unloaded since JVM start process_runtime_jvm_classes_unloaded_total
> 1.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_load_1m gauge
> # HELP process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_load_1m Average CPU load of the whole system for the last minute
> process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_load_1m 2.15087890625 1660037708660
> # TYPE system_cpu_usage gauge
> # HELP system_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" of the system the application is running in system_cpu_usage 0.4666666666666667
> 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_threads_states_threads gauge
> # HELP jvm_threads_states_threads The current number of threads having NEW state jvm_threads_states_threads{state="runnable"} 6.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_threads_states_threads{state="timed-waiting"} 4.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_threads_states_threads{state="terminated"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_threads_states_threads{state="new"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_threads_states_threads{state="blocked"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_threads_states_threads{state="waiting"} 2.0
> 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes Max size of long-lived heap memory pool jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes 4.294967296E9 1660037708660
> # TYPE system_cpu_count gauge
> # HELP system_cpu_count The number of processors available to the Java virtual machine system_cpu_count 8.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_threads_live_threads gauge
> # HELP jvm_threads_live_threads The current number of live threads including both daemon and non-daemon threads jvm_threads_live_threads
> 12.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_threads_daemon_threads gauge
> # HELP jvm_threads_daemon_threads The current number of live daemon threads jvm_threads_daemon_threads 8.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent gauge
> # HELP jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent The percentage of long-lived heap pool used after the last GC event, in the range [0..1]
> jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent{area="heap",pool="long-lived"}
> 0.0047217607498168945 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total counter
> # HELP jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total Incremented for an increase in the size of the (young) heap memory pool after one GC to before the
> next jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total 5.0331648E7 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_gc_overhead_percent gauge
> # HELP jvm_gc_overhead_percent An approximation of the percent of CPU time used by GC activities over the last lookback period or since
> monitoring began, whichever is shorter, in the range [0..1]
> jvm_gc_overhead_percent 0.0034007331860589907 1660037708660
> # TYPE disk_free_bytes gauge
> # HELP disk_free_bytes Usable space for path disk_free_bytes{path="/Users/anuragk/workspace/ts/demo/otel/java/hello/."} 1.89101027328E11 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_memory_committed_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_memory_committed_bytes The amount of memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use
> jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space"}
> 6029312.0 1660037708660 jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace"} 4.358144E7
> 1660037708660 jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
> 'profiled nmethods'"} 1.212416E7 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space"}
> 6291456.0 1660037708660 jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space"} 5.24288E7 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
> 'non-nmethods'"} 2555904.0 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen"} 3.7748736E7
> 1660037708660 jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
> 'non-profiled nmethods'"} 4063232.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes Size of long-lived heap memory pool after reclamation jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes 0.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE system_load_average_1m gauge
> # HELP system_load_average_1m The sum of the number of runnable entities queued to available processors and the number of runnable
> entities running on the available processors averaged over a period of
> time system_load_average_1m 2.15087890625 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_uptime_seconds gauge
> # HELP process_uptime_seconds The uptime of the Java virtual machine process_uptime_seconds 11.542 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes An estimate of the memory that the Java virtual machine is using for this buffer pool
> jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="mapped - 'non-volatile memory'"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="mapped"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="direct"} 16384.0
> 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_buffer_count_buffers gauge
> # HELP jvm_buffer_count_buffers An estimate of the number of buffers in the pool jvm_buffer_count_buffers{id="mapped - 'non-volatile
> memory'"} 0.0 1660037708660 jvm_buffer_count_buffers{id="mapped"} 0.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_buffer_count_buffers{id="direct"} 2.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_cpu_usage gauge
> # HELP process_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" for the Java Virtual Machine process process_cpu_usage 0.3913746438746439 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_classes_unloaded_classes_total counter
> # HELP jvm_classes_unloaded_classes_total The total number of classes unloaded since the Java virtual machine has started execution
> jvm_classes_unloaded_classes_total 1.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_files_max_files gauge
> # HELP process_files_max_files The maximum file descriptor count process_files_max_files 10240.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_files_open_files gauge
> # HELP process_files_open_files The open file descriptor count process_files_open_files 19.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_threads_peak_threads gauge
> # HELP jvm_threads_peak_threads The peak live thread count since the Java virtual machine started or peak was reset
> jvm_threads_peak_threads 12.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
> # HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch. process_start_time_seconds 1.66003769719E9 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_memory_max_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_memory_max_bytes The maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for memory management
> jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space"}
> 1.073741824E9 1660037708660 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace"} -1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'"}
> 1.22908672E8 1660037708660 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space"} -1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space"} -1.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
> 'non-nmethods'"} 5840896.0 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen"} 4.294967296E9
> 1660037708660 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
> 'non-profiled nmethods'"} 1.22908672E8 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_gc_pause_seconds histogram
> # HELP jvm_gc_pause_seconds Time spent in GC pause jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation
> Pause"} 0.003 1660037708660 jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of
> minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",le="5.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="10.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="25.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="50.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="75.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="100.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="250.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="500.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="750.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="1000.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="2500.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="5000.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="7500.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="10000.0"} 1.0 1660037708660
> jvm_gc_pause_seconds_bucket{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
> Evacuation Pause",le="+Inf"} 1.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_classes_loaded_classes gauge
> # HELP jvm_classes_loaded_classes The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine
> jvm_classes_loaded_classes 9409.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_memory_used_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_memory_used_bytes The amount of used memory jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space"}
> 5853584.0 1660037708660 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace"} 4.315976E7
> 1660037708660 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
> 'profiled nmethods'"} 1.2106752E7 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor Space"} 5671744.0
> 1660037708660 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space"}
> 8388608.0 1660037708660 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'"}
> 1277696.0 1660037708660 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen"} 2.0279808E7 1660037708660
> jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled
> nmethods'"} 4001920.0 1660037708660
> # TYPE disk_total_bytes gauge
> # HELP disk_total_bytes Total space for path disk_total_bytes{path="/Users/anuragk/workspace/ts/demo/otel/java/hello/."}
> 4.94384795648E11 1660037708660
> # TYPE jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes gauge
> # HELP jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes An estimate of the total capacity of the buffers in this pool
> jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes{id="mapped - 'non-volatile memory'"}
> 0.0 1660037708660 jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes{id="mapped"} 0.0 1660037708660 jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes{id="direct"} 16384.0
> 1660037708660 ```
> ````

- Received metrics

> ````
> # HELP otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_log_records Number of log records failed to be added to the sending queue.
> # TYPE otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_log_records counter otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_log_records{exporter="prometheus",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 0
> # HELP otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_metric_points Number of metric points failed to be added to the sending queue.
> # TYPE otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_metric_points counter otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_metric_points{exporter="prometheus",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 0
> # HELP otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_spans Number of spans failed to be added to the sending queue.
> # TYPE otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_spans counter otelcol_exporter_enqueue_failed_spans{exporter="prometheus",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 0
> # HELP otelcol_exporter_sent_metric_points Number of metric points successfully sent to destination.
> # TYPE otelcol_exporter_sent_metric_points counter otelcol_exporter_sent_metric_points{exporter="prometheus",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 5576
> # HELP otelcol_process_cpu_seconds Total CPU user and system time in seconds
> # TYPE otelcol_process_cpu_seconds counter otelcol_process_cpu_seconds{service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 2.17
> # HELP otelcol_process_memory_rss Total physical memory (resident set size)
> # TYPE otelcol_process_memory_rss gauge otelcol_process_memory_rss{service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 6.5077248e+07
> # HELP otelcol_process_runtime_heap_alloc_bytes Bytes of allocated heap objects (see 'go doc runtime.MemStats.HeapAlloc')
> # TYPE otelcol_process_runtime_heap_alloc_bytes gauge otelcol_process_runtime_heap_alloc_bytes{service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 9.784448e+06
> # HELP otelcol_process_runtime_total_alloc_bytes Cumulative bytes allocated for heap objects (see 'go doc runtime.MemStats.TotalAlloc')
> # TYPE otelcol_process_runtime_total_alloc_bytes counter otelcol_process_runtime_total_alloc_bytes{service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 3.9931936e+07
> # HELP otelcol_process_runtime_total_sys_memory_bytes Total bytes of memory obtained from the OS (see 'go doc runtime.MemStats.Sys')
> # TYPE otelcol_process_runtime_total_sys_memory_bytes gauge otelcol_process_runtime_total_sys_memory_bytes{service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 2.944308e+07
> # HELP otelcol_process_uptime Uptime of the process
> # TYPE otelcol_process_uptime counter otelcol_process_uptime{service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 388.883801875
> # HELP otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size Number of units in the batch
> # TYPE otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size histogram otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="10"}
> 26
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="25"}
> 28
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="50"}
> 32
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="75"}
> 32
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="100"}
> 32
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="250"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="500"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="750"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="1000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="2000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="3000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="4000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="5000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="6000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="7000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="8000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="9000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="10000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="20000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="30000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="50000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="100000"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_bucket{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",le="+Inf"}
> 75
> otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_sum{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 5576.000000000002 otelcol_processor_batch_batch_send_size_count{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 75
> # HELP otelcol_processor_batch_timeout_trigger_send Number of times the batch was sent due to a timeout trigger
> # TYPE otelcol_processor_batch_timeout_trigger_send counter otelcol_processor_batch_timeout_trigger_send{processor="batch",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0"}
> 75
> # HELP otelcol_receiver_accepted_metric_points Number of metric points successfully pushed into the pipeline.
> # TYPE otelcol_receiver_accepted_metric_points counter otelcol_receiver_accepted_metric_points{receiver="prometheus",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",transport="http"}
> 5576
> # HELP otelcol_receiver_refused_metric_points Number of metric points that could not be pushed into the pipeline.
> # TYPE otelcol_receiver_refused_metric_points counter otelcol_receiver_refused_metric_points{receiver="prometheus",service_instance_id="57f37a9a-5825-48b3-a8a2-240ee4c52656",service_version="0.56.0",transport="http"}
> 0 ```
> ````

[image: Architecture diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I also added `io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-runtime-metrics` as a runtime library in my application. Then I get some metrics like:

```
process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha",pool="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 2555904.0 1675781958779
...
process_runtime_jvm_memory_init{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha",pool="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 2555904.0 1675781958779
...
process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha",pool="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 5836800.0 1675781958779
...
process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_load_1m{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha"} 0.63 1675781958779
process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_utilization{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha"} 0.009925090776389015 1675781958779
process_runtime_jvm_threads_count{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha",daemon="false"} 1.0 1675781958779
process_runtime_jvm_threads_count{otel_scope_name="io.opentelemetry.runtime-metrics",otel_scope_version="1.22.1-alpha",daemon="true"} 21.0 1675781958779
```

Still missing metrics like `jvm_memory_used_bytes` though